# Can Use JQ Insted of PHP for Webdevelopment

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

can  we use JQ insted of php for developing website. which one is more preferable. I think we can also use JQ for web development.Using JQ we can Execute MySql query like php. Which One is better? and why?

Comment: What in the blue blazes is JQ? jQuery? jQuery is javascript/client-side.

Comment: You need to get a clue about what Javascript and JQuery are first, and what they are in relation to a server side programming language.

Comment: You can't "execute mySQL through jQuery" by the way.

Comment: NB [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) is a language on its own (for JSON processing), with no connection to JQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP is for the backend, and JavaScript (jQuery) is for the frontend.  You need a PHP backend to make SQL queries, and you can use jQuery for client-side (web browser) things.

Comment: Thanks for give me right  information about my confusion b/w php and JQ.

Answer (score 0):

Actually speaking **PHP and Jquery both are enterly different**
*PHP* is **server side language** and *Jquery* is **client-side language**

we can use PHP for executing datas and manipulation on our server but if you Jquery alone you can perform manipulation is client side only.
For example you can use PHP for database actions and Jquery for web page validation.